# Underscore.js adding if/else to each function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am currently using a [clndr.js](https://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/) calendar and [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) templates.

Looking for some help implementing an `if/else` statement within the underscore `<% _.each` function.

```
<div class="days">
    <% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
    <div class="event <%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>">
        <div class="number"><%= day.day %></div>
        <% _.each(day.events, function(event){ %>
             <div class="event <%= event.val %>"></div>
        <% }) %>
    </div>
    <% }); %>
</div>
```

At the moment `<div class="event <%= event.val %>"></div>` is shown for each day in the calendar where an event exists, which is great. However, I also want to add a div for days when an event does not exist:

```
<div class="days">
    <% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
    <div class="<%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>">
        <div class="number"><%= day.day %></div>
        <% _.each(day.events, function(event){ %>

             # if the event exists, show this div
             <div class="event <%= event.val %>"></div>

             # else if the event does not exist, show this div:
             <div class="event none"></div>
        <% }) %>
    </div>
    <% }); %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that it's within a `each` callback doesn't change a thing. [Underscore's template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) can use JavaScript directly.

```
<% if (event && event.val) { %>
    <div class="event <%= event.val %>"></div>
<% } else { %>
    <div class="event none"></div>
<% } %>
```

Or since your example is trivial, the following would be enough.

```
<div class="event <%= event.val || 'none' %>"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. just tested and the `else` doesnt appear to get executed in the loop with the code you provided.

Comment: @user3939059 it really depends on what your data is. I changed my answer a little to cater more closely to your case.

Comment: sorry if i am being slow here, but would the `<% _.each(day.events, function(event){ %>` iterate through days where no events exist? or does it only iterate over items where an event exists? (still can't get the else to execute)

Comment: @user3939059 You don't provide enough information in the question for me to help you further. You could use `console.log(day.events)` to see what's inside the object.

Comment: thanks very much for your help. i have solved my problem based on the answer you have given.